# What could cause iterating over an array in Meteor template to produce an extra value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have the following code in a Meteor Blaze template:

```
<template name="showCalled">
    {{called}}
    <br>
    {{#each called}}
      {{this}},
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Called is a property of the data context where this template is used.  I am then getting the following results when the page renders:

4,2,6,2,0,0,0

4, 0, 2, 6, 2, 0, 0,

Note the extra element in the second location and the final element being dropped.  The initial list produced by the `{{called}}` is the correct one.  I'm completely stumped as to what could cause this behavior.

If I refresh the page, it works fine - I only get this behavior when the template updates reactively.

The difference is always an extra element in the second place, though it's not always 0.  It is deterministic (as far as I can tell) and seems to be related to what was there before.  Specifically the value entered in that second place seems to be the value that was in the second place of the correct array prior to the update.

Is this just a Meteor bug or is there something I could be doing to cause it?

UPDATE: I get this behavior even if I manually set the value of `called` to a static array in the helper function, though then it inserts the extra value in the 5th place.

Comment: are you saying you're getting data that's not in your collection, or that it's the correct data set in an unexpected order?

Comment: Data that's not in the collection.

Comment: can you post a full prototype that shows this behavior? i tried what you're saying, including updating the array reactively, and it works as expected.

Comment: I don't see an extra element in the second row, just a different order: one of your 3 zeros is printed in second position instead of its position. To me this is because of the {{#each}} that doesn't necessarily keep your order as it's asynchronous.

Comment: @zim I can't prototype it because I can't generate this behavior.  This is a fairly large application, and nowhere else does it exhibit this behavior.

Comment: In some cases, the value is one which does not appear elsewhere in the array, @MathieuK.  Also, even if the helper returns a static array, I can create this behavior, so it doesn't make sense that it would be a timing/asynchronous issue.  That is, if I call the reactive property in the helper (in order to trigger the reactivity) but then return [4,2,6,2,0,0,0] it still does it.

Comment: I'm seeing this kind of issue as well, wonder if it relates to reordering elements? https://github.com/meteor/blaze/issues/231 did you figure it out?

Comment: I just solved it for my end, this helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35473008/57344 - I tried the random trick, turned out I had 'mixed' objects in the array I was rendering, e.g [{ email: "a@b.com" }, ""]